# I spoiled Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, installation, channel

I am using IBM Watson Studio Jupyter Notebook. When I tried to add a new channel http://anaconda.org with !conda config --append channels https://anaconda.org. Now, when I trying to install any package I getting a error:

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://anaconda.org/noarch/repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.786398
CF-RAY: 55dbd84b6f44bf00-FRA

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://anaconda.org

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.
```

Comment: `anaconda.org` is not a channel. What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to install geocoder package. But default channels is not available it.

Answer (score 0):

https://anaconda.org is not a channel.  You will need to remove it from your config via:

```
conda config --remove channels https://anaconda.org
```

Comment: Can I go back to default settings of Anaconda?

Comment: delete your `.condarc` file located in your HOME or USERPROFILE folder.